# Change AlertifyJS message background color

Tags: alertifyjs

I need to change the background color of the message popup since it's difficult to read (white notification on white site background)

I've seen [here](http://alertifyjs.com/notifier/notify.html) how to customize the custom message using

`// .ajs-message.ajs-custom { color: #31708f;  background-color: #d9edf7;  border-color: #31708f; }`

how do I customize the message one?

My code is `alertify.message(e.response.Message, 5);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default message uses the class named `.ajs-message`. If you don't want to use a custom class as per the link you shared, then override the default message class:

```
/* css overrides */
.ajs-message { color: #31708f;  background-color: #d9edf7;  border-color: #31708f; }
```